# Visual Composer - Custom Element not displaying correctly in admin editor

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I've created a new custom element for Visual Composer and it's all working fine, except that it doesn't look very nice in the backend page editor

The screenshot below shows one custom element and then my custom element beneath.

The first one has nicely formatted parameters in the page editor, but mine does not.

Can someone walk me through what to do to style my admin output nicely please.

[image: Admin Screenshot]

Comment: what code did you use to create the custom component?